# Binary file created in python differs from perl file

Tags: python, perl

I have the following issue when I create a binary file with python and with perl I see a different outcome in the file for the same data.

Example - python:

```
id_hex = binascii.hexlify(id.encode()).decode()
kool_hex = binascii.hexlify(kool.encode()).decode()
did_hex = binascii.hexlify(did.encode()).decode()
mode_hex = binascii.hexlify(mode.encode()).decode()
gogo_hex = binascii.hexlify(gogo.encode()).decode()

# Write to file
with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(binascii.unhexlify(id_hex))
    file.write(b"\x00" * (32 - len(id) // 2))
    file.write(binascii.unhexlify(kool_hex))
    file.write(binascii.unhexlify(did_hex))
    file.write(binascii.unhexlify(mode_hex))
    file.write(binascii.unhexlify(gogo_hex))

file.close()
```

The above code will create a file with this entry:
B202111290000000.....

Example - perl:

```
#print $Key, "\n";
open FILE, ">$filename" or die "Unable to create or open the keybox.bin file $!";   

foreach my $i ( 0...(length($id) - 1 ) )
{ 
  my $char = substr($id, $i, 1);
  my $ascii = sprintf("%2x", ord($char));
  print FILE pack("H2",$ascii);
}
foreach my $i ( 0...(32 - length($id) -1) )
{
  print FILE "\x00";
}
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($kool)/2 - 1 ) )
{
  my $char = substr($kool, $i*2, 2);
  print FILE pack("H2",$char);
}
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($did)/2 - 1 ) )
{ 
  my $char = substr($di, $i*2, 2);
  print FILE pack("H2",$char);
}
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($mode)/2 - 1 ) )
{ 
  my $char = substr($mode, $i*2, 2);
  print FILE pack("H2",$char);
}
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($gogo)/2 - 1 ) )
{ 
  my $char = substr($gogo, $i*2, 2);
  print FILE pack("H2",$char);
}
close FILE or die "Unable to close the keybox.bin file $!";
```

The above code will create a file with this entry:
��2+8�>�*@]�00009.��1ŀ�r��8��....

Why does it differ and how do I have to change my python code to get the same result?

Comment: A clear statement concerning the input data type of id, kool, hex etc would be helpful. I don't get the reason for the hexlify/unhexlify encode/decode pairs but from the output it seems, that one hexlify too much is executed.

Comment: *"The above code will create a file with this entry: B202111290000000"* Please provide examples of the input data id, kool, ... such that we can try reproduce. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: What's your question? You don't understand the Perl code, or there's something you don't know how to do in Python. Don't ask to translate --SO is not a code-writing service-- ask one of those questions.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify whether you problem is understanding the Perl code or how to do something in Python. Given the lack of any mention of an inability to do something in Python, I'm assuming the former. This is made more likely by how badly the Perl program is written.

The short version is that all those loops could be replaced with the following:

```perl
print FILE pack( 'a32 H* H* H* H*', $id, $kool, $did, $mode, $gogo );
```

In English,

1. `$id` is a string of bytes. We print it, padded to 32 bytes (on the right, with NULs).
2. `$kool` is a string of hex text. We convert these to bytes and print them.
3. `$did` is a string of hex text. We convert these to bytes and print them.
4. `$mode` is a string of hex text. We convert these to bytes and print them.
5. `$gogo` is a string of hex text. We convert these to bytes and print them.

This is the equivalent in Python:

```py
file.write( id.ljust( 32, "b\x00" ) )
file.write( binascii.unhexlify( kool_hex ) )
file.write( binascii.unhexlify( did_hex ) )
file.write( binascii.unhexlify( mode_hex ) )
file.write( binascii.unhexlify( gogo_hex ) )
```

More details about the specifics follows.

---

```perl
my $ascii = sprintf("%2x", ord($char));
print FILE pack("H2",$ascii);
```

is a very complicated way to write

```perl
print FILE $char;
```

so

```perl
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($id) - 1 ) )
{ 
  my $char = substr($id, $i, 1);
  my $ascii = sprintf("%2x", ord($char));
  print FILE pack("H2",$ascii);
}
```

is equivalent to

```perl
print FILE $id;
```

`$id` is assumed to be a string of bytes (a string where each character has a value in 0..255 inclusive).

If `$id` is a string of decoded text, it's effectively encoded using iso-8859-1 or UTF-8 first (depending on the string).

---

Then we have this:

```perl
foreach my $i ( 0...(32 - length($id) -1) )
{
  print FILE "\x00";
}
```

It can be simplified to:

```perl
print FILE "\x00" x ( 32 - length( $id ) );
```

The point of this is to pad the id to 32 bytes. As such,

```perl
print FILE $id;
print FILE "\x00" x ( 32 - length( $id ) );
```

can be replaced with

```perl
print FILE pack( 'a32', $id );
```

---

Next, we have a bunch of stuff of the form

```perl
foreach my $i ( 0...(length($kool)/2 - 1 ) )
{
  my $char = substr($kool, $i*2, 2);
  print FILE pack("H2",$char);
}
```

This simplifies to

```perl
print FILE pack( "H*", $kool );
```

It takes a string of hex, and converts to the corresponding bytes (e.g. `"414243"` ⇒ `"\x41\x42\x43"`).